# What will trigger a spam warning on a "First question"?

Tags: discussion, spam

Checking the review queue for "first questions", the first question in the queue was accompanied by the message "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully".

The question, [TeX4ht does not generate correct paragraphs when I use in-line footnotes and KOMA-script](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682173) , looks perfectly reasonable, although the topic (`tex4ht`) isn't one I'm particularly well-versed in.

What characteristics of a post can trigger this sort of spam warning?  (I've observed that "flag" isn't offered as an option on questions/answers in the review queues,  That would often be convenient.)

(I'm familiar with real spam, and immediately flag it when I see it.)

Comment: It shows if the IP address has recently posted spam. Search up "SpamRam" on Meta.SE and you'll find what I mean.

Comment: @gparyani -- Thank you.  My former employer's site was at one time infiltrated by a bad actor who did send out a bundle of spam, resulting in the site being blackballed to the detriment of all employees just trying to get legitimate work done.  The OP of the question I cite seems to have been a victim of a similar mishap.